# Deleting ssl.conf a problem in apache set up?

Tags: ssl

To stop warnings from a free ssl cert I set up a while back and not knowing how to undo it I ended up deleting my ssl.conf file in the etc/ssl folder but now I am wondering if that comes with apache by default and necessary for running other programs?

The problem I was having besides the warnings of untrusted site because have multiple sites running off the one IP , every time https preceded any of the sites they would naturally go to root site instead of individual sites which is something I had to somehow stop but I am sure my methodology is all wrong. At least now  https site not found until I can pay for a certificate. What SHOULD I have done?

```
ca-bundle.crt  ca-bundle.trust.crt  localhost.crt  make-dummy-cert    Makefile     renew-dummy-cert
```

These are exact certs located in /etc/ssl so I could recreate that folder if I wanted but I won't because I think it was created when I went through process of setting up untrusted ssl cert. I don't even know where I can EDIT those registration details but I would love to know.

Comment: give us the exact error that the browser is throwing.

Comment: @strugee I just need to know if the ssl.conf file is a default configuration file in apache and if so how can I get it back without having above problems of site warnings and redirections?

Comment: well, you'll need to give us more details. specifically, your distribution/package manager.

Comment: linux version 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.i686 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Mar 12 21:42:46 UTC 2013

Comment: "CentOS" would have sufficed. you should use YUM to figure out what came with Apache.

Comment: Oh really???? that's interesting.

Comment: if you don't know how to do that, I would ask a new question.